# React Navigation array props

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

react-navigation navigate in array unexpected tokens ?

```
const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
navigate('Properties', { 
    list.map((item) => {
       ["module"+item.id]:this.state["module"+item.id]
    }) 
});
```

Returns error:

> Unexpected token, expected ";"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, when you provide a single expression arrow function that returns an object, you have to wrap that object with parentheses, otherwise the interpreter thinks the braces are a block, and not the object root.

```
list.map((item) => ({
   ["module"+item.id]: this.state["module"+item.id]
}))
```

Second, it looks like you're trying to create the `params` object from a list of values.
But the result of the `map` you wrote, is a list of objects, not an object.

One of the ways to create that object is by using the [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) function:

```
list.reduce((accumulator, current) => (Object.assign(accumulator, {["module"+current.id]: this.state["module"+current.id]})), {});
```

But perhaps a more performant and simpler way would be to just do it with a local side effect:

```
function prepareParams(list) {
  let result = {};
  list.forEach(item => result["module"+item.id] = this.state["module"+item.id]);
  return result;
}
```

And then in your navigate:

```
navigate('Properties', prepareParams(list));
```

Answer (score 1):

Navigation params have to be in object format so you have to add a **key**

```
navigate('Properties', { someKey: list.map((item) => { ... }) });
```

Comment: thanks answer. key ["module"+item.id]: - value this.state["module"+item.id]
Variable key.

Comment: I don't understand your answer, please explain.

Comment: @VeriMerkezi he's saying to replace `someKey` with your key, not what's in the `list.map`